# Counting the same positional bits in postgresql bitmasks

Tags: postgresql, binary, bitwise-operators, bit-shift, bitmask

I am trying to count each same position bit of multiple bitmasks in postgresql, here is an example of the problem:

Suppose i have three bitmasks (in binary) like:

**011011011100110

100011010100101

110110101010101**

Now what I want to do is to get the total count of bits in each separate column, considering the above masks as three rows and multiple columns.

**e.g** The first column have **count 2**, the second one have **count 2**, the third one have **count of 1** and so on...

In actual i have total of 30 bits in each bitmasks in my database. I want to do it in PostgreSQL. I am open for further explanation of the problem if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it by using the `get_bit` functoin and a couple of joins:

```
SELECT sum(bit) FILTER (WHERE i = 0)  AS count_0,
       sum(bit) FILTER (WHERE i = 1)  AS count_1,
       ...
       sum(bit) FILTER (WHERE i = 29) AS count_29
FROM bits
   CROSS JOIN generate_series(0, 29) AS i
   CROSS JOIN LATERAL get_bit(b, i) AS bit;
```

The column with the bit string is `b` in my example.

Comment: Its helpful, any shorter approach where i can minimize the number of statements?

Comment: It is only a single statement. And I cannot think of a simpler one. The data model is not perfect for that kind of query.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the bitwise and `&` operator and bigint arithmetic so long as your bitstrings contain 63 bits or fewer:

```
# create table bmasks (mask bit(15));
CREATE TABLE

# insert into bmasks values ('011011011100110'), ('100011010100101'), ('110110101010101');
INSERT 0 3

# with masks as (
  select (2 ^ x)::bigint::bit(15) as mask, x as posn
    from generate_series(0, 14) as gs(x)
)
select m.posn, m.mask, sum((b.mask & m.mask > 0::bit(15))::int) as set_bits
  from masks m
       cross join bmasks b
 group by m.posn, m.mask;

┌──────┬─────────────────┬──────────┐
│ posn │      mask       │ set_bits │
├──────┼─────────────────┼──────────┤
│    0 │ 000000000000001 │        2 │
│    1 │ 000000000000010 │        1 │
│    2 │ 000000000000100 │        3 │
│    3 │ 000000000001000 │        0 │
│    4 │ 000000000010000 │        1 │
│    5 │ 000000000100000 │        2 │
│    6 │ 000000001000000 │        2 │
│    7 │ 000000010000000 │        2 │
│    8 │ 000000100000000 │        1 │
│    9 │ 000001000000000 │        2 │
│   10 │ 000010000000000 │        3 │
│   11 │ 000100000000000 │        1 │
│   12 │ 001000000000000 │        1 │
│   13 │ 010000000000000 │        2 │
│   14 │ 100000000000000 │        2 │
└──────┴─────────────────┴──────────┘
(15 rows)
```

Comment: i need to sum the counts of **ON** bits of the same position of all the available bitmasks, for example if there are 30 bitmasks available and the 1st bit is ON of the all 30 bitmasks then the sum (count) of the first bits will be **30**, and this goes for all the masks,

Comment: @AbdulWakeel  That is exactly what this does.